# Spring Annotation not working in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Any have problem of annotation doesnt work in Kotlin?

```
@Column(unique=true, nullable = false)
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
var name: String = "",

@Size(max = 100)
var description: String = ""
```

I can save into database with empty string and the unique constraint also not working via the annotation. Anyone have similar issue before ? Kindly advise :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3498476/4754790

Comment: Does it works with plain java? Do you try same with pojo?

Comment: i doing in Kotlin, so i never try in Java. Just wondering how could it be work to prevent in server side instead of database side. It's actually my first time use the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

When using Kotlin, you need to apply the constraint validators on the getter methods. This should work:

```
@Column(unique=true, nullable = false)
@get: Size(min = 1, max = 50)
var name: String = "",

@get: Size(max = 100)
var description: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your issue is with Kotlin exactly.

[@Size and @Pattern annotation are not working in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344676/size-and-pattern-annotation-are-not-working-in-spring-mvc)

It is possible that you have missed the org.hibernate:hibernate-validator package in your dependency, but without more information I cannot be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to

```
@field: Size(max = 100)
var description: String = ""
```